# Dynamics CRM: Unable to change record owner

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

Re: Dynamics CRM 2015 On-Prem

We have a strange issue that started happening today. In short, we cant change any record owners. I even tried on a newly created entity. After changing the owner, whether its manually selecting the owner or using the assign feature, the form refreshes upon saving and it reverts back to the previous owner. No, we don't have any new `OnSave`/`OnLoad` Java scripts or any new workflow/plugins. The only change to the environment was that we rolled back update 0.3, and we since reinstalled it.

**Update**

I think you're right Jacob. I tried upgrading the org to 7.03, but its failing. It's seemingly looking for something that doesn't exists "subscriptionstatisticsoutlookbase". Is it supposed to be a table? Can I manually create this?

```
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'SubscriptionStatisticsOutlookBase'.
```

**Update 2**

I'm updating and tagging the SQL folks. I'm working with PSS but so far nothing. Im getting the same error when trying to upgrade to 2016, so perhaps this is a clue. I copied the SQL statement from the logs to a SQL query, and of course IntelliSense is throwing the same error. I wonder if some SQL guru can shed some light on this. See screenshots below.

[SQL Code resulting in an exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RD9nY.png)

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqBTp.png)

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1eOk.png)

Comment: `The only change to the environment was that we rolled back update 0.3, and we since reinstalled it.` That's quite an "only" change you've got there. Have you looked at the logs? Any remnants/artifacts in your roles from  "only" upgrading and rolling back a major update?

Comment: True, it might be a big only (though its not a major SP update, just hotfixes), but I've since reinstalled it. As far as logs, if you're asking about trace logs, I don't see any errors.

Comment: At this point I would be inclined to rollback to working backup, or contacting Microsoft for support.

Comment: Yeah, I opened a case with PSS. Ill report back the outcome

Comment: The owner of the records has a license?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like i figured it out while waiting endlessly for PSS.

The issue I faced was related to the DB missing tables, I don’t know how and why these tables are linked to changing the owner of a record, but I noticed the complaint about the missing tables when trying to upgrade the org to 7.03. Well actually, the tables are probably not related to the issue, its just that the DB was in an inconsistent state, and these tables were the reason I was not able to bring it back to 7.03. I basically carefully reviewed the upgrade log files.  It failed when trying to create a View from a table that It could not find. The error was “object not found”. There were a total of 4 tables. The upgrade log file didn’t first report on all 4 tables because it stopped as soon as it found the first missing. So I grabbed the DB from a functional 7.03 Dynamics Org, found the tables, and created a Create script for each missing table. The critical part was that I needed to close and reopen deployment manager to allow the upgrade process to pick up the new tables. See script below. Once I created the 4 tables, the upgrade process was successfully able to create the required Views and the upgrade to 7.03 was successful. Upgrading the org to 7.03 resolved the issue.

```html
/***** Table 1 SubscriptionStatisticsOutlookBase *****/

USE <DBName>_MSCRM
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SubscriptionStatisticsOutlookBase](
       [ObjectTypeCode] [int] NOT NULL,
       [FullSyncRequired] [bit] NOT NULL,
       [SubscriptionId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SubscriptionStatisticsOutlookBase] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED

(
       [SubscriptionId] ASC,
       [ObjectTypeCode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SubscriptionStatisticsOutlookBase] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_SubscriptionStatisticsOutlookBase_FullSyncRequired]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [FullSyncRequired]
GO

 

/******* Table 2 SubscriptionSyncEntryOfflineBase ******/

USE <DBName>_MSCRM
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SubscriptionSyncEntryOfflineBase](
       [ObjectTypeCode] [int] NOT NULL,
       [VersionNumber] [bigint] NOT NULL,
       [ObjectId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
       [SubscriptionId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
       [SyncState] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SubscriptionSyncEntryOfflineBase] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
       [SubscriptionId] ASC,
       [ObjectId] ASC,
       [ObjectTypeCode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

/***** Table 3 SubscriptionSyncEntryOutlookBase ****/

USE <DBName>_MSCRM
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SubscriptionSyncEntryOutlookBase](
       [SyncState] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
       [ObjectTypeCode] [int] NOT NULL,
       [ObjectId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
       [VersionNumber] [bigint] NOT NULL,
       [SubscriptionId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SubscriptionSyncEntryOutlookBase] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
       [SubscriptionId] ASC,
       [ObjectId] ASC,
       [ObjectTypeCode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

   /****** Table 4 SubscriptionStatisticsOfflineBase *****/

USE <DBNAme>_MSCRM
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SubscriptionStatisticsOfflineBase](
       [FullSyncRequired] [bit] NOT NULL,
       [SubscriptionId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
       [ObjectTypeCode] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SubscriptionStatisticsOfflineBase] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
       [SubscriptionId] ASC,
       [ObjectTypeCode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SubscriptionStatisticsOfflineBase] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_SubscriptionStatisticsOfflineBase_FullSyncRequired]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [FullSyncRequired]
GO
```